# eclipse android programming error in an Java file and XML file : cannot be resolved or is not field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made a simple android convert application, but I got this

> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type convert cannot be resolved or
>   is not a field    TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line
>   29    Java Problem"
>
> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type dollar cannot be resolved or
>   is not a field    TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line
>   25    Java Problem"
>
> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type dtor cannot be resolved or is
>   not a field   TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line 27 Java
>   Problem"
>
> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type main cannot be resolved or is
>   not a field   TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line 24 Java
>   Problem"
>
> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type rtod cannot be resolved or is
>   not a field   TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line 28 Java
>   Problem"
>
> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type rupiah cannot be resolved or
>   is not a field    TugasfebActivity.java   /tugasfeb/src/tugas/feb line
>   26    Java Problem"

can you guys tell me how to fix this?

```
package tugas.feb;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TugasfebActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView dollars;
    TextView rupiah;
    RadioButton dtor;
    RadioButton rtod;
    Button convert;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dollars = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.dollar);
        rupiah = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.rupiah);
        dtor = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.dtor);
        rtod = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rtod);
        convert = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.convert);
        convert.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(dtor.isChecked()){
            convertDollarsToRupiah();
        }
        if(rtod.isChecked()){
            convertRupiahToDollars();
        }
    }

    protected void convertDollarsToRupiah(){
        double val = Double.parseDouble(dollars.getText().toString());
        rupiah.setText(Double.toString(val*12000));
    }
    protected void convertRupiahToDollars(){
        double val = Double.parseDouble(rupiah.getText().toString());
        dollars.setText(Double.toString(val/12000));
    }
}
```

main.xml

I also got a problem here "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.  main.xml    /tugasfeb/res/layout    line 11 Android XML Format Problem"

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/widget33"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#F0E68C"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 </RelativeLayout>

 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/convert"
     adroid:layout_width="313px"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/widget38"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
     android:text="Convert"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     />

 <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/widget38"
     android:layout_width="320px"
     android:layout_height="217px"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/widget39"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         amdroid:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Dollar"
         android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/dollar"
         android:layout_width="123px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="22sp"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/widget40"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Rupiah"
         android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/rupiah"
         android:layout_width="127px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="22sp"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <RadioGroup 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/dtor"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Dollar ke Rupiah"/>
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/rtod"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Rupiah ke Dollar"/>
     </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you're missing a root element in your xml

Comment: It looks like you want to have a `RelativeLayout` as the root layout because some of the children have layout attributes related to positioning in a `RelativeLayout`, like `android:layout_below="@+id/widget38"` in a `Button`. To achive this, move the line `</RelativeLayout>` to the bottom of your xml file.

Comment: @deHaar i have put </RelativeLayout> to the bottom xml file, this error occurred [2019-02-27 20:38:29 - tugasfeb] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: Can you post the entire error messages for each, the code before and the one after my suggestion was applied. You should really use the supported IDE for Android, that is Android Studio. The Eclipse plugin is not supported anymore.

Comment: @deHaar error displayed when </RelativeLayout> i dont put it on bottom of my xml file [2019-02-27 20:57:30 - tugasfeb] Error in an XML file: aborting build. and error displayed when </RelativeLayout> i put it on bottom of my xml file [2019-02-27 21:01:03 - tugasfeb] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: the error result are the same

Comment: There is a typo in line 11, too... It is `adroid:layout_width="313px"` but should be `android:layout_width="313px"` (missing n in android). Correct that and then move the line to the bottom as suggested before. The only thing that may cause an error afterwards is the missing xml declaration above the root element (or have you just omitted it here?).